# jquery mobile panel events not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, panel

I can't seem to tie into the jquery mobile panel events as seen here

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/panels/events.html

```
$(document).on('beforeopen', ".ui-panel", function() {
    alert('open');
});
$(document).on('beforeclose', ".ui-panel", function() {
    alert('close');
 });
```

or

```
 $(document).on('open', ".ui-panel", function() {
    alert('open');
});
$(document).on('close', ".ui-panel", function() {
    alert('close');
 });
```

or even using context on the panel

```
$('.ui-panel',context).on('open', function() {
    alert('opened');
});
```

where context is a jquery object variable of the current page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking a look at the **[jQuery mobile API](http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#event-beforeopen)**

It provides examples for `beforeopen(event, ui)` which is a type of `panelbeforeopen`, they provide these examples in the API documentation:

1) Initialize the panel with the `beforeopen` callback specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).panel({
  beforeopen: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

2) Bind an event listener to the `panelbeforeopen` event:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "panelbeforeopen", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

Comment: cool I guess I should look at the api docs more than demo docs, easy solution.

Comment: I will admit the link you provided can cause confusion but it does list the event name as the `type` on this page. See http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/panels/events.html

Comment: The "panelbeforeopen" part got me.  I was doing .on("beforeopen")

Answer (score 1):

you must insert your code inside $( document ).on( "pageinit", function( event, data ){.....

```
   $(document).on( "pageinit", function( event, data ){
     $( ".ui-panel" ).on( "panelbeforeclose", function( event, ui ) {
        // your code here
     } );
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the correct div for it to work.  Your selector needs to reference the div that has data-role="panel".

```
$(window).on("load",function(){

    $( "#your-panel-id" ).on( "panelclose", function( event, ui ) {
        alert ('hi') ;
    }); 
});
```